# How to pass on a value as parameter via url to another page

Tags: images, customization, urls, parameter

I'm dealing with a problem I can't solve myself. I did a few hours of research about it, but I didn't manage to make it work. I want to send a parameter via the url to the page I'm forwarding to and based on the value of this I want to show a image.
Im using the Hana Code Insert Plugin to get my js used in WP. I'm relatively new to WP and have little to no knowledge in PHP, so please consider this.

**The Hana-contents are as following:**

**shortcut galleryLink and getSelected_05:**
http://www.abload.de/gallery.php?key=updfCGrl

**The contents of the site are as following:**

> toat.me/test-for-ids/

Gallery:
[hana-code-insert name='galleryLink' /]
Finished...

> toat.me/resize-your-image-now/

|img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-119" alt="" src="http://toat.me/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/blank-t-shirt_white_big.jpg" width="700" height="700" /| [hana-code-insert name='getSelected_05' /]

Note: I had to replace the <> tags of the img with | in order to show it in this post.
I'm looking forward to helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in a php file such as a template, you can use $_GET to extract the url variables. For example, if your url was mydomain.com/page?color=blue you would print it on screen by:

```
<?php echo $_GET['color']; ?>
```

This would print "blue". So to make a conditional statement out of this, you could do:

```
<?php if( $_GET['color'] == 'blue' ) {
    echo '<img src=''>';
} elseif( $_GET['color'] == 'red' ) {
    //do something else
}
```

Query strings are stored in the $_GET variable as an associative array. Now, if you want to do query strings in Wordpress posts/pages, you need to create a function to read query strings via shortcode. It looked like you were doing this inside template files though so I will leave that solution out, unless you need it - then just let me know and I'll edit this.

Comment: As I said above, I use a plugin to get the code used in Wordpress posts/pages, I'm writing the code inside the plugin and then just access it with its shortcode. I tried it the way you described above, but it shows me the php code at the page and just the img-tag from the else is executed and it displays this picture

Comment: Could you please edit your post to add the fuction to read query strings.